# Changing the root path of .Net Web Application with Custom Project URL

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, web-deployment, gulp

I am building a SPA which uses the client side task runner like Gulp. After performing tasks I would copy the compressed, minified and gzipped files to the dist folder. Below is the project structure.

[image]

Also I have custom project URL

[image]

1. I would want to set the `dist`  directory as the root of my application which means that instead of going to `http://localhost/GulpFromVSTest/dist/index.html` , I should be able to directly goto `http://localhost/GulpFromVSTest/` and it should route me correctly to the index.html page.
2. When I am copying new assets over to `dist`, VS does not add them to the project automatically which might create issues when I publish to server. Is there any approach that I can follow?

I have been researching for sometime to see if there is any good solution for this but couldn't fine any.

Answer (score 0):

I solved your first issue serving the static files directly with the [Katana middleware](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Static%20Files%20on%20IIS) which allows to remap the root folder to another one (but you'll have to disable the native IIS handler for static resources which is faster than a managed one).

For your second question a possible but "hacky" solution would be to exclude from your project every reference to the dist folder then to unload the project and edit it manually adding this new item reference:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="dist\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

This way visual studio will update the solution explorer including all the dist folder files every time you reload the project, which is not ideal but probably solvable with some ide extension, but the files will be included in the Azure deployment, which was my goal. Remember to not include any "dist" file from Visual Studio or you'll see them duplicated in the solution explorer after the project reload.